# Applying CSS styling to only the first <li> in the root of a nested list

Tags: html, css

i want to apply the CSS only first li but `:first-child` apply to all first child of every ul

here is my [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/jassi9911/w47LD/)

```css
#menu-navigation li:first-child{
   color:red;
}​
```

When applied to this HTML:

```html
<ul class="nav" id="menu-navigation">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us
        <ul>
            <li>Our Team</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

...both "Home" and "Our Team" turn red.

Comment: 'http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp' check title here

Comment: *-sigh-* You just got [W3Fooled](http://w3fools.com). `:first-child` is a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element. (I don't always post W3Fools comments, but there are times when they're absolutely necessary.)

Comment: Pseudo-*classes* like `li:first-child` select the `li` **if** it's the first child. (This is similar to classes - `li.first` selects an `li` **if** its class list contains "first"). Pseudo-*elements* describe different blocks to the element being selected. For example, `span:first-letter` creates a *new* block surrounding the first letter of the `span`, and then selects *that*

Comment: Also note that in CSS3, pseudo-*elements* should be [delimited with a double colon](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements) `li::first-letter`, but this is optional for the pseudo-elements defined in CSS2 (`:first-line`, `:first-letter`, `:before` and `:after`). That's probably the source of a lot of confusion

Comment: @Gareth thnx for the information

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use the child selector:

```
#menu-navigation>li:first-child{
   color:red;
}​
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/w47LD/3/

Comment: i tried it in my code but not showing red color, did you apply in my code

Comment: @Jassi See the fiddle I've added to this answer; only "Home" is red. If this is not the case for you, what browser are you using? IE6?

Comment: @Jassi Looks "correct" to me in FF12 on Windows 7. When I view the link in this answer, only "Home" is red.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to just use an id/class?

```
<li class="red"> Our Team </li>

.red
{
  color: red;
}



Alternatively you could use an ID...



<li id="red"> Our Team </li>

#red
{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Mike, solutions like this run counter to idea of CSS and keeping your style separate from your formatting. If there is a solution to apply a change to bunch of tags without adding extra HTML, that's the route you should go.