# How to style differently only the first list item from unsorted list

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical menu like the one you can see [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NtDLw/). The thing is - I want to have something like header. As you can seen, now my structure is this:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <ul>
        <li class="first"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I could add another `<div class="menu-header">` on top of the `<ul>` but I think that the it would be much easier and appropriate to just change the firs `<li>` item to looks like a header. However if I just add a class like I'm doing in the example the final output is the same (the styles are not overriden. I can use `!important` but this is kind of last resort.

Even though it's not a ton of CSS I would like to change only some things and other (like width for example) to be left as they are for all other elements. So how can I do this? Is there more CSS-like approach than just adding `!important` to each style I want to override?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying CSS styling to only the first <li> in the root of a nested list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451988/applying-css-styling-to-only-the-first-li-in-the-root-of-a-nested-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two alternate ways to achieve this.

**Alternate 1.**

Use the `first-child` of the class `first` of the li which is a child of `ul`

`ul li.first:first-child`

**For Instance,**

```
ul li.first:first-child{
    /* Your CSS Values. */
}
```

**Alternate 2.**

Use `first-child` of `li` which is nested inside its main parent `#wrap` (which is a unique identifier). Use this alternate only if you do not want to use the class `first` on `li`

`#wrap ul li:first-child`

**For Instance,**

```
#wrap ul li:first-child{
/* Your CSS Values. */
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is any of this approaches keep the styles that are not overriden? Do I have to set again width, height and other stuff that I want to be the same as those of the other elements?

Comment: You just need to declare those attributes that you want to change with any of these approaches, keeping the existing attributes as it is which you might have already declared earlier. - @Leron

Answer (score 3):

I'd give the CSS selector `first-of-type` a try.

```
li:first-of-type {
    ...
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp

Answer (score 3):

Your problem with the example given is called [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gbonanome/f3dGb/1/) for a working example.

Without using of classes, to style the first-element of a list I suggest you to use the [pseudo-class `first-child`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/selectors/pseudo-classes/%3afirst-child).

```
#wrap ul li:first-child {
    background: none;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the provided example, it's clear that I should use pseudo class, it's just my first time I have to.